# How can I pass a route with an id in a function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want onClick of a delete button, I would get the id of a selected item and be able to perform a delete operation with the id, but right now the value I am getting is undefined..

This is what the route looks like

```
 http://localhost:9000/customization/cooperations/terminal/undefined/delete
```

If I can get the value, then the delete operation will be successful

This is my code block

```
      const handleDelete = () => {
      history.push(`${match.url}/${terminalEntity.id}/delete`);
     console.warn(terminalEntity.id);
     };
```

Right now with this function, I can not get the value of the id, but I am getting undefined and it maps to this route indicated above.

====>      http://localhost:9000/customization/cooperations/terminal/undefined/delete

Comment: looks like your variable terminalEntity.id is undefined

Comment: how does terminalEntity looks like? It looks like it is not as it should be

Comment: Its really tough man, but I am trying to figure out a way to get the id of the row when an event is clicked

Comment: Thanks guys for your response. My goal is to make onClick of button a modal pops asking for permission before delete. I asked the ques here ===> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71431052/react-bootstrap-modal-is-popping-up-onclick-of-function incase you wish to render your assistance.